Update a Table Column in PostgreSQL within an AWS Glue Job Using PySpark SQL Queries
I am working with a large amount of data from Square, storing it in PostgreSQL using AWS Lambda functions. Afterward, I run AWS Glue ETL jobs to transform this data into the required format.
Currently, I have two Glue jobs:
One job transforms the order data from the "square_order" table and stores the aggregated data in a separate table called "square_dashboard."
Another job transforms customer data from the "square_customer" table.
The issue I am facing is that I need to update the "square_dashboard" table based on the aggregated data from the "square_customer" table.
I have a SQL query that works fine in PostgreSQL to perform this update:
-- First, update existing rows in the square_dashboard table
UPDATE square_dashboard sd
SET new_customer = subquery.new_customers
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, DATE(created_at) AS customer_date,
           COUNT(*) AS new_customers
    FROM square_customer
    GROUP BY user_id, DATE(created_at)
) AS subquery
WHERE sd.user_id = subquery.user_id
  AND sd.date = subquery.customer_date;

-- Insert new rows for cases where the date doesn't exist
INSERT INTO square_dashboard (user_id, date, new_customer, day)
SELECT subquery.user_id, 
       subquery.customer_date, 
       subquery.new_customers,
       TO_CHAR(subquery.customer_date, 'Dy')
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, DATE(created_at) AS customer_date,
           COUNT(*) AS new_customers
    FROM square_customer
    GROUP BY user_id, DATE(created_at)
) AS subquery
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM square_dashboard sd 
    WHERE sd.user_id = subquery.user_id
      AND sd.date = subquery.customer_date
);

Now, I need to perform this update within my AWS Glue job. Is there a correct way to execute these SQL queries directly in a Glue job, or should I take a different approach?
I attempted to run the SQL queries directly in the AWS Glue job using PySpark's spark.sql() method, expecting it to update the square_dashboard table in PostgreSQL based on the aggregated data from the square_customer table. My expectation was that the SQL queries would execute successfully within the Glue job, just as they do in PostgreSQL directly. However, I encountered difficulties in integrating these queries into the Glue job's workflow, especially in terms of establishing a connection to the PostgreSQL database and executing the SQL statements correctly.

Are the lambdas written in python? You can do the import of the data in Glue as well.  Regarding SQL part, I will respond later  with a workaround that I use to execute all kind of querie.

@Bogdan No, the lambda functions are in Node.js, I am fetching data from square through lambda functions and using AWS Simple Queue Service (SQS) to store data in postgreSQL.

Create a dummy dataset and use glueContext.write_dynamic_frame to inject your custom SQL script. The following script is used on Redshift, please update the connection_option to suit your database type.
def execute_custom_SQL_script(sql_script):


    data = [("dummy dataset!")]
    columns = ["message"]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

    # Convert the Spark DataFrame to a DynamicFrame
    dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dynamic_frame")
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
        frame=dynamic_frame,
        catalog_connection="your_catalog_connection_",
        connection_options={
            "database": "your_database",
            "dbtable": "dummy_table",
            "preactions": "",
            "postactions": sql_script + '; drop table if exists dummy_table;'
        },
        redshift_tmp_dir="s3://123123123123",
        transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame_iteration")


Hi, do you think this should work for a custom query that performs a LOAD FROM S3 command? what action should I use on the glueContext?

You can give it a try but why dont use glue in order to load the s3 file? Use the visual tool, if the script its to complicated.

I did use a Glue Visual ETL succesfully, but it takes 7 hours to load an 11GB file. I'm trying to achieve the same using the LOAD FROM S3 command, which should take less time. In the visual ETL job I had to create a custom classifier because the file has fixed-length columns, and apply a couple of transformations. None of these would be necessary if I could run the LOAD FROM S3 command. I would really appreciate it if you could provide any help on how to do it

I will think of a solution. let's keep in touch.

Have you tried to increase the workers size? Have you seen improvements?

Hi Bogdan, it turned out it was the testing environment I was working on, the cluster is too small. When going to production, the ETL job finished succesfully in 70 minutes, using 10 workers of type G1x. Thanks for your support
